# Проблема при наследовании методов и свойств класса

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.querySelector(".parent");
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.click.bind(this));
  }
  click(e) {
    let action = e.target.dataset.action;
    if (action) {
      this[action](e.target);
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  doSmth() {
    console.log("do something");
  }
  doSmth1() {
    console.log("do something1");
  }
}

new Parent();
new Child();
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-action="doSmth">
  Parent
  <div class="child1" data-action="doSmth1">
    Child1
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы информация о элементе и функция прослушивателя событий хранилась в родителе, а методы, которые будет запускать функция, уже в потомках. На данный момент код выше будет работать только если передавать отдельно каждому классу элемент для прослушивания событий. При этом появляется ограничение, они должны быть на одном уровне вложенности.

Comment: Что именно не работает, когда вы в самом родительском классе определяете `this.element`? И приложите пожалуйста минимально воспроизводимый код в Code Snippet, а не просто отрывок кода

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Craith777/9ap381L0/1/ вот накидыл пример, при клике выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: this[action] is not a function at Parent.click

Comment: @ГрязныйАркадий Хотел тоже глянуть, да вот jsfiddle не работает в России( у меня так точно ).

Comment: @Ceri Скоро подъедут мои изменения, если их примут, конечно :)

Comment: Я просто не знаю куда еще  скинуть можно )

Comment: @ГрязныйАркадий cюда же в Code Snippet, я же сказал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас всё работает насколько я вижу, единственное вам вместо `if(action)` надо проверять `if(this[action])`:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.element = document.querySelector(".parent");
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.click.bind(this));
  }
  click(e) {
    let action = e.target.dataset.action;
    if (this[action]) {
      this[action](e.target);
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  doSmth() {
    console.log("do something");
  }
  doSmth1() {
    console.log("do something1");
  }
}

new Parent();
new Child();
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" data-action="doSmth">
  Parent
  <div class="child1" data-action="doSmth1">
    Child1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь )